# Locked out, Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I pulled my Raspberry Pi out from storage and have forgotten my username and password. I don't have access to a microSD reader at the moment. Is there any way I can simple reset the Pi to it's default? I have no important files on there, so I'm fine with wiping and starting over (as long as I still have Raspbian installed).

How would I go about wiping and starting over from the login screen?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to wipe and start over by restarting (control-alt-delete) and hold down shift. I then installed Raspbian, which wiped the card and started the Raspberry Pi from scratch.